# awk - if column = null

Tags: bash, awk

Using awk, how would you assign 'null' a value to read?

I'm sure there's a set character for this, I just can't find it.

For example,

I've got a string of awk like this:

```
awk '
$3==24{print "stuff"}
$3==23{print "stuff"}
'
```

I need to know how to account for blank colums using the same format so that if $3 = blank {print "stuff"}

Thanks!

Comment: If `$3` is blank, do you expect to have non-blank values for `$4` etc on the same line?  What's up with `$3 == ""` as the condition?

Comment: $3's the last column in the file. Some lines only have 2 columns

Comment: So, `NF == 2` or `NF == 3` tells you whether $3 is set or not, doesn't it?  Incidentally, you might think about using `$3 == 24 { print "stuff"; next }` as an action, since that saves `awk` checking whether 24 is equal to 23 (it isn't).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk '
    $3==24{print "stuff"}
    $3==23{print "stuff"}
    !$3{print "null"}
' file.txt
```

If you need to process `$3` if it's zero (`false` for `awk`), try doing this :

```
!$3 && $3 != 0{print "null"}
```

Comment: Yuuuup, just had to switch !$1 to !$3 :)

Comment: What happens if the value in `$3` is 0?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : added a note about this

Comment: I think `$3 == ""` would be clearer than `!$3 && $3 != 0`. In this case it sounds like OP actually wants to test for `NF<3`.

Answer (score 9):

In default awk processing, there's no such thing as a "blank" column.

Fields are delimited by whitespace, i.e., by one *or more* whitespace characters (tabs and spaces, basically).  So given this input:

```
this that the_other
foo       bar
```

for the first line `$1`, `$2`, and `$3` are `this`, `that`, and `the_other`, respectively, but for the second line `bar` is `$2`, regardless of how many blanks there are between the first and second fields.

You can have empty fields if you specify a different field separator:

```
$ ( echo 'this:that:the_other' ; echo 'foo::bar' ) | awk -F: '{print $3}'
the_other
bar
```

Or, if you prefer to set the field separator in the script itself:

```
$ ( echo 'this:that:the_other' ; echo 'foo::bar' ) | \
    awk 'BEGIN { FS = ":" } {print $3}'
the_other
bar
```

But you can use a regular expression as the field separator:

```
$ ( echo 'this that the_other' ; echo 'foo  bar' ) | \
  awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[ ]" } {print $3}'
the_other
bar
```

(Some *very* old Awk implementations might not support it regular expressions here.)

The regular expression `"[ ]"` doesn't get the same special treatment that the space character does.

References to the GNU Awk manual:

[Default field splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Default-Field-Splitting.html):

> Fields are normally separated by whitespace sequences (spaces, TABs,
>   and newlines), not by single spaces. Two spaces in a row do not
>   delimit an empty field. The default value of the field separator `FS` is
>   a string containing a single space, `" "`. If awk interpreted this value
>   in the usual way, each space character would separate fields, so two
>   spaces in a row would make an empty field between them. The reason
>   this does not happen is that a single space as the value of `FS` is a
>   special case -- it is taken to specify the default manner of delimiting
>   fields.
>
> If `FS` is any other single character, such as `","`, then each occurrence
>   of that character separates two fields. Two consecutive occurrences
>   delimit an empty field. If the character occurs at the beginning or
>   the end of the line, that too delimits an empty field. The space
>   character is the only single character that does not follow these
>   rules.

and [Using Regular Expressions to Separate Fields](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html).

But be careful with this; either you'll have to modify the file to use a different separator, or your parsing will be sensitive to the number of blanks between fields (`foo bar` (with one blank) will be distinct from `foo  bar` (with two blanks)).

Depending on your application, you might consider parsing lines by column number rather than by awk-recognized fields.

Comment: wrt `"at least in GNU Awk, you can use a regular expression as the field separator"` - that's true of all awks. GNU awk is only special in this regard by also allowing the RS to be a regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - didn't catch this earlier